# Number of ways to pick keys out of two bags with unequal probabilities?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I haven't posted too many questions before so I apologize if this comes across as very simple.

> I have two bags with 10 keys each. The probability of getting a key from Bag 1 is $0.3$ and the probability of getting a key from Bag 2 is $0.7$. I pick a new key out of a bag in each round. What is the probability that Bag 2 will have 3 keys left in it when I have picked out all the keys from Bag 1?

Comment: 10 keys each. Sorry about that- edited.

Comment: The next question is, what have you tried? What are your thoughts on this? If you have this problem from a book, then which chapter it is in its usually a big hint. Have you tried applying that? It doesn't matter if it failed, that is why you are here, after all. Just give us some background to work with.

Comment: My answer for this is ((0.3)^10)*((0.7)^7), because 10 keys have been chosen from Bag 1 with probability 0.3 each and another 7 have been chosen from Bag 2 with 0.7 each. However, this doesn't seem to jive... I don't know where I'm messing up. Should I be taking into account that the order of the keys chosen or does that not matter? I am pretty stumped

Comment: You are pretty close. The only thing missing is taking the order into account. What you have there is the probability of one specific sequence of bag choices (for instance, the probability of "first I draw seven keys from bag 2, ten I draw ten keys from bag 1" is one such sequence). All such sequences with ten bag 1's and three bag 2's are equally likely. What is left is counting how many such sequences there are, keeping in mind that the last one must be a bag 1.

Comment: That makes sense- thank you!

Comment: No problem. Next time, remember to include what you have already done in the question post itself. Generally, posts that do that are better received by the community here.

Comment: @mDe Have you the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. We know that the last key is from Bag 1, and, before that, we picked out, in some order, 9 keys from Bag 1 and 7 keys from Bag 2.

Comment: Thank you Robert! I think I've got it- I wasn't taking the ordering into account previously.